# Python swap confusion

Tags: python-3.x

Just try

```
arr=[1,2,4,3];i=2
arr[i],arr[arr[i]-1]=arr[arr[i]-1],arr[i]
```

and then try

```
arr[arr[i]-1],arr[i]=arr[i],arr[arr[i]-1]
```

what exactly am I missing here?

Is this a conceptual fault?

Comment: Please add a problem statement which explains what this code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Because the index has an array that is calculated during the substitution. For your first case, it can be treated as

```
arr[2], arr[arr[2] - 1] = arr[arr[2] - 1], arr[2]
arr[2], arr[arr[2] - 1] = 3, 4
# So, arr[2] is now 3 and the second equality is not working as you expected
arr[2], arr[3 - 1] = 3, 4
arr[2], arr[2] = 3, 4
```

However for your second case,

```
arr[arr[2] - 1], arr[2] = arr[2], arr[arr[2] - 1]
arr[4 - 1], arr[2] = 4, 3
arr[3], arr[2] = 4, 3
```

which gives the correct result. It can be modified that

```py
arr = [1, 2, 4, 3]
arr2 = arr.copy()
i = 2

arr[i], arr[arr2[i]-1] = arr[arr2[i]-1], arr[i]
print(arr)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]

arr = [1, 2, 4, 3]
i = 2

arr[arr[i]-1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[arr[i]-1]
print(arr)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```